# Swift code issues !=

Tags: swift

I'm having issues when I put not equal to != it displays the alert no matter what.

When I put equal to, it does nothing, but everything looks correct. My code is below, the one I'm having issues with is the passwords don't match then return. I know I connect everything in storyboard because when I click on txtpassword it all lights up green and same with the confirm password as well.

```
import UIKit

class SignupVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var txtUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtPassword: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var txtConfirmpassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtEmail: UITextField!

    @IBAction func signupTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        _ = txtUsername.text;
        _ = txtPassword.text;
        _ = txtConfirmpassword.text;
        _ = txtEmail.text;

        //check empty fields
        if((txtPassword.text?.isEmpty)! || (txtConfirmpassword.text?.isEmpty)! || (txtEmail.text?.isEmpty)!)
        {

         //Display alert
            displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "All fields are required")
            return;
        }
        //check if passwords match
        if(txtPassword == txtConfirmpassword)
        {
            //Display in alert message
            displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Passwords don't match");
            return;
        }
        //store Data

        // Display alert message with Confirmation
    }

    func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
    {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil);

        myAlert.addAction(okAction);

        self.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `txtPassword == txtConfirmpassword` to `txtPassword.text == txtConfirmpassword.text`. No clue why you have 4 lines doing this `_ = txtUsername.text;`

Comment: The is no `!=` in the code but a lot of pointless semicolons.

Comment: What's the point of the lines such as `_ = txtUsername.text;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying

```
    if(txtPassword == txtConfirmpassword)
```

Those are text *fields*:

```
   @IBOutlet var txtPassword: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet var txtConfirmpassword: UITextField!
```

They are not the same text *field* so that test will never pass. What you want to know is whether they contain the same *text* — and you are not testing for that. That would be:

```
    if txtPassword.text! == txtConfirmpassword.text!
```

Comment: And please, stop using unnecessary parentheses and semicolons. This is Swift, not C.